# Ритуал массового сожжения

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Всем, кто хочет помочь с наведением порядка с метками. Есть некоторое количество широко используемых меток (100+ вопросов), использование которых нужно исправить, а в ряде случаев полностью избавиться от меток. Эти метки на большом СО или внесены в чёрный список, или отмечены на сожжение.

В порядке популярности:

- [mvc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) — метка предназначена для вопросов по паттерну MVC. Во всех остальных случаях следует заменить метку на более точную.

  - [asp.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) + [mvc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) > [asp.net-mvc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)
- [api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) — мета-метка, сюда сваливаются все вопросы по API на всевозможных языках. Подлежит полному сожжению.

  - [facebook](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) + [api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) > [facebook](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) + [facebook-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-api)
  - [vkontakte](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte) + [api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) > [vkontakte](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte) + [vkontakte-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte-api)
  - [twitter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) + [api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) > [twitter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) + [twitter-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-api)
  - [history](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) + [api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) > [history-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history-api)
  - [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) + [api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) > [...-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/...-api) (у Гугла зоопарк API, выбрать нужный)
  - и т. п.
- [веб-сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82) — мета-метка, сюда сваливаются все вопросы по веб-разработке. Подлежит полному сожжению. Обычно можно безболезненно удалить, так как есть нормальные метки, описывающие используемые технологии. В противном случае метки необходимо добавить.
- [canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) — неоднозначная метка. На большом СО используется для элемента HTML.

  - [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) + [canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) > [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) + [android-canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-canvas)
  - [wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) + [canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) > [wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) + [wpf-canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-canvas)
- [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) — из-за количества сервисов Google стала мета-меткой. На большом СО внесена в чёрный список. Подлежит сожжению. Следует подбирать конкретные сервисы и API Google, если таковые не указаны в метках.

  - + [google-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api)
  - + [google-search](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search)
  - + [google-chrome](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)
  - + [google-play](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play)
  - + [google-adwords](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-adwords)
  - и т. п.
- [framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework) — для общих вопросов о фреймворках. Если вопрос касается конкретного фреймворка, то метку следует удалить.

  - [entity-framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework) + [framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework) > [entity-framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework)
  - [yii](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) + [framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework) > [yii](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii)
  - [django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) + [framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework) > [django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django)
  - и т. п.
- [script](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) и [скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82) — мета-метки, объединяют все «скриптовые» языки на свете. На большом СО внесена в чёрный список. Подлежит сожжению. Обычно можно безболезненно удалить, так как уже указан язык программирования. В противном случае добавить метку с языком программирования.
- [переменные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5) — мета-метка, так как подавляющее большинство языков программирования поддерживает переменные. Обычно можно безболезненно удалить.
- [интернет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82) и [internet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet) — мета-метка, объединяет все вопросы, касающиеся веб-разработки, а у нас — и настройки сетей. На большом СО занесена в чёрный список. Подлежит сожжению. Обычно можно безболезнено удалить, так как есть более содержательные метки. В противном случае добавить их. (Сделано: [Удалить [интернет] и поместить в чёрный список](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10484/240512))

На этом список самых популярных меток, подлежащих сожжению, кончается.

Пожалуйста, когда исправляете метки, обращайте внимание на содержание вопроса. Если его можно улучшить, улучшайте. Если его следует закрыть, отмечайте тревогой или отправляйте на закрытие. Не забывайте, что правки привлекают к старым вопросам внимание, поэтому важно, чтобы вопросы приводились к надлежащему виду.

Comment: Апнул вопрос. Прошло полгода, но он всё так же актуален.

Comment: Прошерстил [tag:vkontakte-api] и [tag:facebook-api]

Comment: Не согласен лишь с меткой `переменные`. Если вопрос конкретно к переменным, а не к чему либо еще, то эта метка то что надо. Если её удалять, то надо удалить массивы, картежы, данные, типы данных и прочее. Да, все эти метки поддерживаются в подавляющем числе языков, но от  этого они не становятся ненужными.

Comment: @Nofate, разве модераторы не могут сжигать метки не вручную, проходясь по вопросам, а как-то проще?

Comment: @wchistow кнопки "удалить метку" нет, если вы об этом. Только синонимизация/переименование автоматизировано.

Comment: [tag:интернет] недавно [удалили и запретили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13107/532877).

Answer (score 8):

Объединяя две метки в одну, мы теряем ту гибкость, для которой метки были созданы.

Старые форумы на движке phpBB (и аналогичные ему) использовали ветвление форума за счет создания предопределенных разделов. Пользователи лишь создавали подразделы - темы. Таким образом модераторы контролировали набор обсуждаемых тематик. Одной из крупнейших ошибок такого подхода является то, что ветки жестко заданны. Пользователь не может задать вопрос по двум меткам сразу. Например, по алгоритмам и программированию (в этом случае, если нет специально созданной двойной ветки, следует выбрать чего в вопросе больше и задать вопрос в соответствующею тему). Проблема и в том, что предугадать все темы наперед практически невозможно. Как результат, часто вопросы будут задаваться невпопад, а сами знания не будут структурированы, что осложнит поиск информации.

Метки и возможность группировки по меткам превосходно решают эту проблему. Идея объединения нескольких меток в одну, откидывает нас назад к жестко заданным веткам, что на мой взгляд ошибочно.

В каких же случаях стоит объединять метки?

- В тех, когда метка не самодостаточная, то есть не описывает какой-то раздел знаний, технологию, язык и т. д.
- Так же стоит объединять метки, когда по отдельности одна из меток (из тех, что мы хотим объединить) не может существовать у нас на сайте, например, в сообществе никто не задает общие вопросы о ВКонтакте, а спрашивают только об API социальной сети.

Comment: В примерах формул выше я пытался адекватно разделить случаи, когда метка добавляется, когда заменяется, когда удаляется. Вы с каким конкретно слиянием меток не согласны? Огласите весь список, пожалуйста. ©

Comment: Из переведённого вами списка, как мне кажется, объединение метки mvc и canvas чуть-чуть излишне.

Comment: (1) Желающие найти статьи по паттерну MVC вряд ли будут заинтересованы всем зоопарком библиотек, использующих паттерн. А если будут заинтересованы, то лишь малая часть использует этот тег. Специалистом по паттерну MVC во всех библиотеках быть невозможно. То есть это по всем критериям мета-тег. (2) canvas — это разрешение конфликта. canvas в разных библиотеках — это *абсолютно* разные вещи (где контект для рисования, где панель с ручным размещением контролов, где ещё что), поэтому использовать тег для всех случаев невозможно, приходится разделять.

Comment: MVC вполне можно рассматривать отдельно от библиотек.

Comment: Главная задача меток - структурировать информацию. Объединяя несколько меток в одну мы усложняем поиск. Представьте, что кто-то решит создать выборку вопросов по `android`. В случае использования объединенной метки, ни один вопрос с меткой `android-canvas` не попадёт в выборку. Или такие вопросы должны содержать метку `android` и `android-canvas` одновременно, что выглядит избыточно. Фильтрация меток должна основываться на сочетании меток, а не на их количестве. Также должна быть возможность совместного их использования при почтовых подписках и создании выборок.

Comment: @Nofate Поэтому я и не сказал, что метку надо удалять. Надо лишь исправить часть использований тега не по назначению.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Правильно с точки зрения SO будет добавить две метки: android, android-canvas. См. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+android-*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+android-*) Это не избыточность, это разрешение конфликта. Между метками на СО и понятиями в программировании должно быть взаимно-однозначное соответствие. Если для одного понятия используется несколько меток, то метки объединяются как синонимы. Если одна метка соответствует разным понятиям, то она разделяется на несколько меток для разрешения неоднозначности.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Да, появляется небольшая избыточность в терминологии меток, и новички могут не всегда правильно использовать метки (например, поставить только android-canvas), но это уже надо исправлять вручную или подписываться на android-*. Та же проблема существует с версиями языков: если используется метка с версией, то основную метку тоже нужно указывать (например, python и python-2.x). / С точки зрения чистоты системы тегов это оптимальный подход, потому что иногда одному слову соответствуют совершенно разные понятия.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Напимер, bootstrap — это и инициализация приложения, и фронт-энд фреймворк от Twitter. Canvas здесь в абсолютно такой же ситуации: если кто-то заинтересован в HTML Canvas, то ему совершенно не нужны ни WPF Canvas, ни Android Canvas: единственное, что их объединяет — это слово в английском языке. С точки зрения поиска и подписок неоднозначности всегда только мешаются, поэтому нужно разрешать конфликты. / Это не что-то, что придумал я. Метки на Stack Exchange испокон веку так работали.

Comment: @Athari А как на счет `android`? Как вы думаете, о чем будет вопрос с такой меткой? На самом деле, о чем угодно, что связанно с этой ОС. Например, о NDK (С/С++), о SDK (Java) или, более того, вопрос про html, контексте мобильной версии сайта! То, о чем будет вопрос определяется набором меток, а не одной. Согласитесь, у нас нет android-c++, android-java или android-html. Почему же тогда должен быть android-canvas?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Специалистом по Android быть можно, это нормальное состояние. API, я так понимаю, что для плюсов, что для джавы один и то же — вопрос синтаксиса. Знаешь одно — подскажешь в другом, даже если не знаешь язык. Также упрощает ситуацию, что для андроида почти всегда пишут на джаве, а не на плюсах — можно не заморачиваться (вопросы: 112К java, 2.5К c++). Мобильные версии сайта тегать "android" почти всегда неверно: для андроида есть разные браузеры, и они не прибиты гвоздями к оси. Тег android имеет смысл, только если какой-то глюк проявляется исключительно на андроиде.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Ну и если постоянно разрабатываешь под андроид, то, скорее всего, знаешь какие-то нюансы поведения браузеров, поэтому тоже можешь подсказать. А вот в случае с canvas ситуация абсолютно другая: вероятность, что один разработчик отлично разбирается и в нюансах веб-разработки с HTML-ным canvas, и в разработке для Windows на фреймворке WPF, и в разработке на Java для мобильной платформы Android — ничтожно мала.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky И таки деление android на android-c++, android-java и android-html — разделение вопросов, реально объединённых общим — операционной системой; а разделение canvas — это разделение абсолютно не связанных понятий, у которых **из общего только название на английском языке**. Это разные случаи.

Comment: На мой, сугубо не профессиональный взгляд, canvas - это то, на чем рисуют. Canvas ничем не отличается от android, в плане объединения вопросов как метка.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky За андроид не отвечаю, но https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx — на этой "канве" рисовать невозможно, она для совершенно другого.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что этот Canvas нужен за тем же, зачем и все другие.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky В WPF канвас — это просто панель для размещения элементов управления, где элементам управления можно задавать явные координаты, рисовать на нём вручную нельзя; в HTML-ном канвасе никаких элементов управления нет, в канвасе ничего не размещается, это пустая область для рисования всего вручную; в фейсбуке канвас — это фрейм для размещения любого кода HTML. Что между ними всеми общего?