# Что делать с [dllimport]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Про эту метку побудил рассказать вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1296271) вопрос. У нас есть метка [dllimport](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllimport), по которому есть целых 14 вопросов, но эта метка не так однозначна. У неё есть как минимум 3 определения:

- C-шный `__declspec(dllimport)`
- C#-овский `DllImportAttribute`
- Просто импорт DLL, что, в принципе, можно заменить на [dll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dll) и [import](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) (2 метки).

В общем, не знаю, что с нею делать. Самое забавное, что нет метки [dllexport](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllexport) и [declspec](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declspec), но есть метка [dllimport](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllimport), которую можно просто заменить на 2 и к которой приплетают `DllImportAttribute`.

Мне *кажется*, что нужно создать метку [declspec](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declspec), раз уж на то пошло, а метку [dllimport](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllimport) просто удалить (с её заменой (если понадобиться) на соответствующую/-ие метку/-и).

Answer (score 3):

В случае с метками (как и в некоторых других случаях) можно обратиться к enSO, как старшему брату ruSO. Там тоже есть метка [dllimport](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dllimport/info) и используется как для C/C++ так и для C#. Поэтому два первых варианта из вашего списка покрываются явно. Третий вариант (по сути это случай отличных от C/C++/.Net языков) покрывается неявно, когда речь идёт об использовании динамических библиотек в Windows.

Т.о. вроде как и нет никакой проблемы с меткой.

Comment: а почему они не могут ошибаться? и почему мы не можем проявить инициативу?

Comment: @return все могут ошибаться, конечно. Но я не вижу тут ошибки.

Comment: мне как минимум кажется ошибкой, что эта метка — общее м-ду условными [dll-import-attribute], [declspec] и [dll]+[import].

Comment: @return Вы посмотрите на общий уровень беспорядка в метках, и оцените, насколько на фоне него имеет смысл обсуждение метки с всего лишь 14 вопросов. См. например: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320/240512 Проявить инициативу вы можете всегда, просто будьте готовы, что она будет отправлена в долгий ящик за отсутствием мотивации.

Comment: неприятненько...