# Для чего именно нужна метка [вконтакте]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, использование-метки

Я решил разобраться со всеми метками, которые как-либо связаны с социальной сетью VK. Начнём с конца:

- [vk-streaming-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vk-streaming-api) - 3 вопроса, последний 2019 года. Появилось [5 лет назад](https://vk.com/blog/streaming-api), спросом не пользуется.
- [vk-sdk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vk-sdk) - 3 вопроса, последний 2020 года. Возможно про [официальный SDK](https://dev.vk.com/sdk/overview), но это не точно.
- [vkbottle](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkbottle) - 7 вопросов, новая, есть активность. Это [python библиотека](https://github.com/vkbottle/vkbottle).
- [php-vksdk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-vksdk) - 8 вопросов. Это официальная [php библиотека](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk).
- [vk-mini-apps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vk-mini-apps) - 27 вопросов. Это про [платформу приложений от VK](https://dev.vk.com/mini-apps/overview).
- [android-vksdk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-vksdk) - *42* вопроса. [Аналогично от VK](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk).
- [vknet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vknet) - 54 вопроса. Логично, [.NET библиотека](https://github.com/vknet/vk).
- [vkontakte-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte-api) - 2,025 вопросов. Это про [VK API](https://dev.vk.com/api/overview).

---

Так же у нас есть общая метка [вконтакте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5) с 1,215 вопросов. Если со всеми остальными метками понятно, для чего именно они созданы, то для чего конкретно нужна эта метка? Обычно вопросы на SO задаются связанные с VK API или библиотекой, которая работает с VK API. Давайте вместе разбираться.

Comment: Следуя такой же логике: зачем тогда общая метка [tag:telegram], если есть [tag:telegram-bot]? Возможно, есть тонкости взаимодействия с ВКонтакте, которые связаны не с API, а, к примеру, с анализом данных и кода страниц в DevTools.

Comment: Анализ данных ещё возможно (у них есть методы [database](https://dev.vk.com/method/database), снова API), но если анализ страниц с целью парсинга _(не методами API)_, то **НЕТ, нельзя**, нарушается 6.3.9 [vk.com/terms](https://vk.com/terms) _(Пользователю при использовании Сайта запрещается использовать без специального на то разрешения Администрации Сайта автоматизированные скрипты (программы, боты, краулеры) для сбора информации на Сайте и/или взаимодействия с Сайтом и его функциональностью)_.

Comment: На расстановку меток у нас этот запрет не влияет. Если это не запрещено правилами на данном сайте, такой вопрос теоретически может быть задан. Проблема меток компаний давно известна: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320/ Если хотите улучшить ситуацию, добавьте к метке нормальное описание, и укажите, что вместо связки меток [вконтакте]+[api] следует использовать метку [vkontakte-api].

Comment: `"Давайте вместе разбираться"` -- для начала хорошо бы понять, а для чего большинству участников-посетителей SO вообще нужны метки. Т.е. как они **реально** используют этот механизм. О себе могу сказать -- когда читаю заголовки вопросов на главной странице, то заодно бросаю взгляд и на метки. Т.е. меня все тонкости структуры меток той или иной темы практически не интересуют. Осталось понять, а какая часть участников SO поступает так же?

Comment: @avp, если на главной нет интересного, то в ход идут метки по интересующим меня тематиками. Главная обычно заполнена популярными вопросами, а мне нужны не такие популярные.

Comment: @avp В 99% случаев — просто для поиска :)

Comment: @Harry, (и Stanislav Volodarskiy) в таком случае вам скорее всего нужна лишь общая метка для какой-то темы. Я к тому, что метки давно пора бы упорядочить именно в таком плане. Завести 2-3 обязательных метки для каждой темы (одна из них обязательно должна быть в вопросе), а остальные метки вопроса (если ТС их добавляет) оставлять как есть

Comment: У меня тоже аналогично как выше. По метке очень удобно отсеять вопросы в зависимости ЯП, по которому чаще всего отвечаешь или ищешь ответ. А потом уже подробности. Чем-то эта идея напоминает мету, не правда ли?

Comment: @mironovmeow, на мой взгляд, таким комментарием вы как раз и ответили на свой вопрос -- *`"... то для чего конкретно нужна эта метка?"`*. Более общая метка в основном и используется при поиске.

Comment: @avp Следовательно нужно использовать эту метку примерно вместе с другими метками, как `vkontakte-api` или `vksdk`. Звучит вполне логично. Тогда чуть позже отправлю изменения по меткам.

Comment: Посмотрите вот это: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320/%d0%a0%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Откуда взялась метка?**

Так исторически сложилось. Скорее всего, сначала была создана более общая метка ([вконтакте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5)), а потом уже создавались более узкие, это нормально.

**Стоит ли удалять эту метку?**

Я считаю, что нет. Вот причины:

1. В этом нет смысла;
2. Это может быть непросто сделать, с меткой куча вопросов;
3. Есть темы, под которые более "узкая" метка не подойдёт;
4. Ей пользуются;
5. См. дальше.

**Стоит ли удалять редкие метки (из вашего списка)?**

Нет, не стоит. Если понятно о чём они, и у них есть описание (все метки **из вашего списка** понятны, минимум половина имеет описание), то пусть живут. Самое главное, чтобы можно было понять, **как использовать метку и зачем она нужна**. Тогда не важно, сколько с ней вопросов (если вопрос один или их вообще нет, то метку всё же стоит удалить).

**Взгляните на другие проблемы:**

Вообще, на русском `StackOverFlow` есть более важные проблемы с метками, поэтому не стоит сильно беспокоиться, что меток, связанных с вконтакте, многовато =).

Самая главная проблема с метками на `StackOverFlow`, что у многих меток нет описания, и смысл некоторых неясен и неодназначен.

#### Обновление

Нужно сделать синонимами [вконтакте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5) и [vkontakte-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte-api) - ибо про что ещё может быть вопрос про вконтакте на сайте разработчиков.

Comment: *"Вообще, на русском StackOverFlow есть более важные проблемы"* - всегда есть проблемы поважнее. Это не повод, не давать участникам заниматься "пустяками" )

Comment: @Kromster  да, но я имел в виду, что в **данном случае** не нужно удалять метки.

Comment: @Зонтик заметь, я ни слова не сказал про удаление меток. Я только про использование спросил)

Comment: @mironovmeow да, но при малом использовании метки часто возникают мысли об удалении =).