# Объединить метку [long-poll] с [long-polling]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метки [long-polling](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/long-polling) и [long-poll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/long-poll) (9 и 60 соответственно). Как я понимаю, они про одно и то же и используют их одинаково ([два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1246359/418625) [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/869177/418625) вообще используют обе метки). Предлагаю их объединить и оставить первую метку, как сделано на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/long-polling/).

Comment: У меня вопрос по вашим правкам меток, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/832088 . Вы пишите пояснение "Сжигание метки api", в связи с этим вопрос, вы действительно собираетесь вручную удалить эту метку у всех [1800 с лишним вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api)?

Comment: @insolor больше интересен вопрос - зачем сжигать эту метку? В отдельных случаях она явно нужна, например в вопросах просто об апи

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это мета-метка, которую обсуждали, что лучше её не использовать. см: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320/418625

Comment: @insolor Нет, я не планирую по всей метки api проходится. Я только делаю это в разрезе vk / vkapi. И, чаще всего, Добавляю соответствующую метку [tag:vkontakte-api]. Дополнительно стараюсь улучшать вопросы, что бы они оставались полезными и акутальными.

Comment: @mironovmeow на мой взгляд если я задаю вопрос про api - не значит что я вопрос задаю например про вконтакте api или google api, я могу задать вопрос чисто про api - как оно устроено, какое взаимодействие может быть и т.д. так что это обсуждение **8 летней давности Карл!!** брать за основу - полный бред (где и решения то не было вынесено)

Comment: @mironovmeow только вот там нет резолюции, что таки да, будем удалять, нет никакого решения по поводу "сжигания". Если меняете на vkontakte-api, то так и пишите в описании правки, что меняете на более конкретную метку.

Comment: @insolor Хорошо. В следующий раз буду более конкретнее указывать причину редактирования. Спасибо за замечание