Синонимизировать метки на тему [переменные]
Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

variable -> переменные
environment-variables -> переменные-среды

Ещё у нас есть метка global-variables, которую неплохо было бы перевести на русский как [глобальные-переменные].

Переменные среды или переменные окружения?

А потом ещё [tag:Переменные] удалить и запретить :)

@Зонтик, конечно

@andreymal, а разве среда и окружение - не одно и то же?

@Зонтик зачем переменные удалять и запрещать?

@αλεχολυτ, да, скорее всего их придётся на некоторых вопросах именно о переменных оставить.

@αλεχολυτ https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320/532877

@Зонтик если ТС добавил её в список, это еще не значит, что других мнений нет. Так же любой (?) ЯП поддерживает функции, условия, циклы и т.п. Но это ведь не значит, что надо все метки об этом сжечь.

Готово!
updating post history, 59 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 56 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 55 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'variable': [variable] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 621
tag remapping of [переменные] and [variable] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym variable -> переменные was approved!


updating post history, 34 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 31 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 31 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'environment-variables': [environment-variables] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 42
tag remapping of [переменные-среды] and [environment-variables] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym environment-variables -> переменные-среды was approved!


updating post history, 94 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 86 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'глобальные-переменные' doesn't exist, renaming 'global-variables' to 'глобальные-переменные'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [глобальные-переменные] and [global-variables] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym global-variables -> глобальные-переменные was approved!

